# while using django-filter for filtering how to export the filtered values into csv file

Tags: python, django, export-to-csv, django-filter

I have used django-filter module for filtering. Want to export the results into CSV file.

```
def bfs_version_filter(request):
    version_obj = bfs_versions.objects.all()
    filter_obj = version_filter(request.GET, queryset = version_obj)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type = 'text/csv')
    file_name = "version_filter"+str(date.today())+".csv"
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = "'+ file_name +'"' #edited by vennilam
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    for i in filter_obj:
        writer.writerow(i)
    return response
```

Getting below error:
TypeError at /bfslite/version_filter/
'version_filter' object is not iterable

Comment: what is `version_filter()`?

Comment: Shouldn't you access `.qs`, so `version_filter(...).qs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the constructor of a `FilterSet` subclass will not filter the queryset, it will construct an object of that subclass.

You can access the [**`.qs`** attribute [readthedocs.io]](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-primary-qs) to get access to the filtered queryset:

```
def bfs_version_filter(request):
    version_obj = bfs_versions.objects.all()
    filter_obj = version_filter(request.GET, queryset = version_obj).qs
    response = HttpResponse(content_type = 'text/csv')
    file_name = "version_filter"+str(date.today())+".csv"
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = "'+ file_name +'"' #edited by vennilam
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    for i in filter_obj:
        writer.writerow(i)
    return response
```